# How to customize the phonecalltask popup?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone, phone-call

how can I customize the popup for phonecalltask? I want my own buttons to be placed and my own message, but "Dial" gets shown by default

Comment: maybe an alternative you can suggest?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no alternative to this. Microsoft has permitted us to use the dialer but customizing it is not in our hands.